# Do all Functors have a natural transformation from the identity functor?

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

Considering categories C and D, and functor  $F:C\to D$, and the identity functor $Id_C : C\to C$. Is there always a natural transformation $n: Id_C \to F$, where n(X) is just F(X)?

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y\\
@Vn(X)VV @Vn(Y)VV \\
F(X) @>{F(f)}>> F(Y).
\end{CD}$$

It seems to me that you should always be able to define said natural transformation and in this sense every Functor is/has a natural transformation from the identity functor of its domain category. But I haven't seen this confirmed anywhere and in fact have seen things that seem to suggest it is not necessarily the case. Am I missing something?

Inspired by this question. [Functors that has a natural transformation from identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075000/functors-that-has-a-natural-transformation-from-identity#)

EDIT: Thanks to Dan Doel for an solid example. I also just realized that the first comment was correct $F: C \to D$ and $Id_c: C \to C$ only have the same target if F is an endofunctors, and if not then the definition of a natural transformation isn't even well formed (which was probably the root of my confusion).

Comment: these functors have different targets, no?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. For starters it's not guaranteed arrows $X\to F(X)$ even exist

Comment: @FShrike Don't those arrows part of the functor? Since the functor associates for every object X in C an object F(X) in D? 

Also I edited the question for formatting and some more context.

Comment: No? There is an object $F(X)$ yes. There is *not* an arrow $X\to F(X)$ necessarily, nowhere in the definition of functor is that given

Comment: I'm must not understand the formalization well enough to get the distinction. As in, what exists and doesn't. If a functor associates X in C to F(X) in D, why can't we equivalently talk about a natural transformation made of of arrows from X -> F(X).

Comment: @segfault I tell you, in the market there exists a shop. I have not told you there exists a road by which you can get to this shop. Sure, you might intuitively expect this to be true, but it is not guaranteed. "Associates" **does not** mean "there exists an arrow between". "Associates" is being used purely conceptually, there is no definitional content to it

Comment: Then what does "associates" mean, formally. It seems really weird that in category theory, which models everything as arrows, if we cannot model this association as arrows

Comment: You are making the classic error of confusing a set and its individual elements, which unfortunately is not easy to explain in natural language. But consider this. $\sin$ is a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. It associates to each real number $x$ another real number $\sin x$. Does this mean there is a function $x \to \sin x$? No!

Comment: What then, would be an example of a functor for which we cannot define such a natural transformation from the identity functor?

Comment: Maybe it isn't clear to me what the moving parts are here. 

We have objects, and arrows between them, and identity arrows must exist and behave like arrows, and the composition of 2 arrows must exist. This all makes sense formally. 
But then we say that F "associates", and that association is not made up of arrows... What *is* it then, precisely. It feels like I am missing a whole piece of the formalization.

Comment: For example, texts seem comfortable saying the identity functor always exists. 
That must be the case if we assume all categories are embedded in categories of categories (with functor as arrows), but why do we assume this outer level "exists"?

Comment: It seems you are (also) confusing the jargon "arrow" for the everyday word "arrow". When category theorists talk about arrows they mean something specific – something formal! – not just anything that might happen to be represented by an arrow in an illustration. "Association" does not mean drawing arrows between things – that's for illustration purposes only!

Comment: Wtf was it closed after it was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is "no." For instance, on the category of sets, there is a functor:

$$
\begin{align}
&F : \mathsf{Sets} → \mathsf{Sets} \\
&F_0(X) = Ø \\
&F_1(f) = id_Ø
\end{align}
$$

This is just a constant functor. Now, a natural transformation $\mathsf{Id} → F$ would require there to be functions from every set into the empty set. However, the only such function is the one from the empty set to itself.

This example can be generalized by using initial objects in other categories. Sometimes there *will* be a natural transformation $\mathsf{Id} → F$ in such scenarios. But if the initial object is [strict](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+initial+object), then the only way this can happen is if *every* object is initial, which would mean that the category is equivalent to the terminal category.